# Determine number of seconds in one year

Tags: sql, oracle

What SQL expression would be able to calculate the number of seconds in any particular year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non leap years:

```
SELECT 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 AS secInYear
FROM dual
```

And in general:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7737/0)**

```
SELECT
  24 * 60 * 60 * (
  CASE 
    WHEN MOD(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate), 400) = 0 
         OR ( MOD(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate), 4) = 0 AND MOD(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate), 100) != 0) THEN 366
    ELSE 365
  END ) AS secInYear
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')) * 86400 SECONDS
FROM
    DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR('2015-12-31') * 24 * 60 * 60 FROM DUAL
```

`DAYOFYEAR` will return 365 for New Years Eve for regular years, and 366 for leap years.

Comment: Although it seems to be documented in 9i, DAYOFYEAR is not recognized in 12c.

Comment: Too bad. Well, OP can try and see if the used Oracle version supports it.